# Python multiple user inputs - go through all inputs before exiting

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, user-input, exit

I am trying to set up a simple user-input menu (non-gui) as follows:

If the user inputs 0:

1. a file is loaded.
2. a menu comes up with options 1-5 prompting
   for another user input from 1 to 5. Now, here, after the first user
   input, some processing is done. Then I would like to ask the user
   for a second user input. This should continue until the user enters
   6 or larger.

Else (if the user does not enter 0)
Print "Error exiting. Please restart program."

Here is what I have:

```
import csv

# Load input file:
choiceloading = input('Please enter 0 to load the input file: ')
if choiceloading == 0:
    with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)

print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print ("1. Action 1")
print ("2. Action 2")
print ("3. Action 3")
print ("4. Action 4")
print ("5. Action 5")

# Get user input:
choice = raw_input('Enter choice [1-5] : ')

# Convert input (number) to int type:
choice = int(choice)

# Perform action based on menu-option selection by user:
if choice == 1:
    print ("Action 1...")
    #processing #1 is done here
elif choice == 2:
    print ("Action 2...")
    #processing #2 is done here
elif choice == 3:
    print ("Action 3...")
    #processing #3 is done here
elif choice == 4:
    print ("Action 4...")
    #processing #4 is done here
elif choice == 5:
    print ("Action 5...")
    #processing #5 is done here
else:
    print ("Invalid entry. You should choose 1-5 only. Program exiting.....please restart it and try again.")
else:
    print ("Invalid entry. You should choose 0 to load the file. Program exiting.....please restart it and try again.")
```

Currently, the program only accepts 1 user input. After processing, it then exits. ex. if the user enters 3, and processing of 3 is complete then the program will exit.

However, I would like to allow the user to enter 1,2,4,5 for processing of 1,2,4,5. Then they should enter >5 to exit.

Question:
After processing, how can this code be changed to allow the user to enter the remaining outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the processing in a loop, like so:

```
while True:
    # Get user input:
    choice = raw_input('Enter choice [1-5] : ')

    # Convert input (number) to int type:
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        print ("Action 1...")
        #processing #1 is done here
    elif choice == 2:
        print ("Action 2...")
        #processing #2 is done here
    elif choice == 3:
        print ("Action 3...")
        #processing #3 is done here
    elif choice == 4:
        print ("Action 4...")
        #processing #4 is done here
    elif choice == 5:
        print ("Action 5...")
        #processing #5 is done here
    else:
        print ("Invalid entry. You should choose 1-5 only. Program exiting.....please restart it and try again.")
        # Add sys.exit() (will have to add 'import sys' to top
    else:
        print ("Invalid entry. You should choose 0 to load the file. Program exiting.....please restart it and try again.")
        # Add sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that the last else is not required. It does not seem to be working. I am able to cycle through all the options, but how do I exit the program completely? That last else was there if the user did not enter 0 to load the file (as they should), but it is not working correctly. Is there a way to exit if "choiceloading" is not equal to 0?

Comment: You need to add `sys.exit()` where you want to end the program and then at the top of the file add `import sys`. You could do it another way as well by putting that entire loop in a function, put a `return` statement where you want to exit, then call the function in your program.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. That worked. All questions here are answered.